# How to pass variable value from phtml JS to block.php?

Tags: magento2, javascript, blocks, phtml

I have a phtml (system.phtml) with `<script>` in it and a variable like `console.log(data)`.

```
<?php $checkcustomer = $block->Customerlogin(); ?>

 <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

  var data= 12345; 
   console.log(data);
  </script>
```

Now i am getting the variable value in console and i also want its value in my block to do further processing on it how can i get `data` variable value in block or controller?

Comment: So you want a value from your JS into your HTML?

Comment: i want value from JS to my PHP block file

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. Please update your question with the code lines.

Comment: Is it ajax call from controller to block?

Comment: nope just js i don't know any approach to send variable value either with ajax or jquery

Comment: Can you provide a use case please? It's difficult to understand what you need to achieve and why.

Comment: i have updated the question @ben